# Ionic time picker Usabilidade

Tags: ionic, time

Boa noite galera, estou tentando implementar esse data picker no Ionic, porém não está dando certo. Alguém já usou ele ? Ou alguém sabe um nesse estilo que dê para utilizar o formato 24h? Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-timepicker

[image: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-timepicker]

Consegui usar esse, porém  o formato é de 12h, teria como colocá-lo com 24h? Obrigado!
Link https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ionic-timepicker-component/

[image: https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/ionic-timepicker-component/]

Answer (score 0):

Porque você não usa o próprio DateTime do Ionic? Ele já vem com a opção de formato 24h.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Na documentação tem um tópico explicando toda a parte de formatos de datas e horas. (Display and Picker Formats)

Comment: chefe não gostou do layout, eu até achei um legal, esse: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker/v/2.1.2, porém não estou conseguindo colocar no formato 24h